# Andengine WakeLock

Tags: android, andengine

Is that mandatory to give `WAKE_LOCK` permission in AndEngine?
If i try to remove this `WAKE_LOCK` permission I am getting SecurityException.

logCat ERROR:

```
01-28 09:57:48.417: DEBUG/dalvikvm(166): Added shared lib /system/lib/libjni_latinime.so 0x437577d0
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225): You have to add
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225): to your AndroidManifest.xml !
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10024 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:178)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:228)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.acquireWakeLock(BaseGameActivity.java:200)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:166)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:83)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2027)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3694)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:655)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1782)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
01-28 09:59:02.966: ERROR/AndEngine(225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you working with GCM??

Comment: no... working on andengine games.

Answer (score 3):

Not required, see: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/engine/options/WakeLockOptions.java#L24 . Use `SCREEN_ON`.

Comment: I tried removing WakeLock option & used screen on But i am getting Security Exception!...

Comment: This guy made AndEngine. That automatically makes his answer THE answer. Please accept it, OP. :)

Comment: @Johnson you did NOT set the `WakeLockOptions` to `WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON` !

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for setting wakelock permission,but it is mandatory because if the screen timer expires(for example 15 or 20 seconds),the screen will be blank,interrupting the game and you have to open(wake) the phone again.So,it is necessery.